# Select only certain parameters when selecting inputs in Jenkins (Groovy) Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I know this is an advanced level question, or at least that's what I feel like it is.

I am creating a jenkins/groovy setup for creating a dashboard (Build with Parameters - in Jenkins) for users to input the values.
The script I am using is:

```
parameters([

    choice(name: "Environment", choices: ['Dev', 'QA', 'PRD'], description: 'Select Env', required: true),

    choice(name: 'Select Type', choices: ['EC2', 'EKS', 'ECS'], description: 'Select type'),

    choice(name: 'permission', choices: ['user', 'service account', 'policy'], description: 'Select permission'),

    string(name: "TeamDL", description: 'Provide Team Name', required: true),

    string(name: "ProductType", description: 'Enter the product name', required: true),

    string(name: 'TeamWork', description: 'Provide team DL', required: true),

])
```

In the above script what I am trying to achieve is, if I select my Environment as 'PRD' then I should be able to only select 'user & service account' or just 'user' or 'service account' (either 1 selection or two selections only) but not all three choices from 'permission' section (from above script).

Not sure how I can achieve this option here.

Any tips how I can conclude my input selection here, appreciate the help.

Cheers!

Multi-Select options from the Jenkins Dashboard (Build with Parameters)

Comment: Out of the box, Jenkins can't help you there. You may have to implement it in Javascript elsewhere. Optionally, you can then use ActiveChoice plugin to get your Javascript code to work on the "Build with Parameters" page.

Comment: What about the opposite? Allow everything in the ui but validate in the backend and throw an error like: Op1 is not allowed for PROD environment ?

Comment: An additional option is to prepare all valid permutations of env/type/permission and present that as a choice. In a later stage, extrapolate the choice into  env/type/permission.

Comment: Appreciate the inputs here.

1. I am not familiar with Javascript, so I will try to leverage other colleague help here.


2. Opposite: Can you please shed some light on your approach and how can I set it up? I need the logic here so I can formulate the jenkins/groovy syntax.


3. Valid Permutations: Same as above pal "Can you please shed some light on your approach and how can I set it up? I need the logic here so I can formulate the jenkins/groovy syntax."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) plugin.